# Facebook video share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share a video via sharer url (https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsirius.isebox.net%2Fmichal%2Ftest-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test%3Fdefault%3Dg5s3e2)

I can't get the video to play in facebook. When I debug using FB's open graph debugger, I get this strange error:

"Share has playable media but will not play inline because it would cause a mixed content warning if embedded. Add a secure_src or make the video src secure to fix this."

I have no idea where to add the secure_src to the header. Notice that og:video:secure_url is already present

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is working now, honestly I have no idea why it wouldn't work before. Here's my bit of meta goodness that works:

```
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://domain.tld/flv.flv">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://domain.tld/flv.flv">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://domain.tld/mp4.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://domain.tld/mp4.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />

<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://domain.tld/mp4.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://domain.tld//mp4.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load the video over HTTPS protocol, the mixed content warning means that your video is loading via HTTP. You can provide your video using two url tags (secure and non-secure).

Comment: If you carefully observe the open graph debugger, you'll notice that I'm already doing that

Comment: Have you tried using https for both urls? Provide the video from the same domain?

Comment: Yeah, I did...made no difference. Try to debug this site: http://vidly.com/h7c6q1, the og tags there look just like mine and that site loads in the debugger fine. I also though that it's because the page itself is not https...tried that and that was also not the reason

Comment: I assume you are not using self-signed certificates, correct? Is that video just a video file, or does it load anything else dynamically? I had this issue with a .swf file.

Comment: That video is in fact coming from vid.ly...I have no control over it. It's not self signed.

Comment: Did you get this working I am now having the same issue?