# Embedding video player html5 iframe in facebook share like YouTube

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube, facebook-opengraph

When something is shared from youtube to facebook, facebook is now showing the youtube html5 player.

If you look up one of their urls (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuS5ZyQhvsk) in the [open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) you can see that they are now providing open graph meta data for their html player as well as the flash one.
[image: Facebook youtube open graph screenshot]

I also have a player that sits in an iframe, and am now including the same tags that youtube is, minus the flash ones as we don't have a flash player, but it isn't working and facebook is giving me this error which doesn't make sense:

> Share has playable media but will not play inline because it would cause a mixed content warning if embedded. Add a secure_src or make the video src secure to fix this.

[image: open graph error for our site]

This is the information facebook is reading:
[image: facebook open graph screenshot for our site]

This is the url as an example that is generating that error: https://www.la1tv.co.uk/player/124/260

All I can think is that Facebook has made some kind of deal with youtube and this isn't available for everyone yet, but that isn't clear from that error.

All of the content on our site is served over https.

Anyone know what's going on or got this working?

I can't find any documentation anywhere on facebook how to do this.

*I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26789256/1048589) a while back when I was trying to get this working but at this time youtube was still only providing the flash player to facebook.*

*It looks like someone else was having a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525006/facebook-video-share).*

Comment: Youtube is testing the feature. When it become available for everyone it will be announced on https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: That's great thanks. Do you know roughly when this might happen? If the tags I have in place are correct, which I think they are, will it be enabled automatically for us or will we need to apply for it somewhere?

Comment: No idea on both questions

Comment: Looks Like Facebook went ahead and allowed the complete opposite; You upload to Facebook and share them on your site, not the other way around- just announced recently at the Facebook F8 event.

||| https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152795634488553 

||| https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads 

||| https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Comment: That's interesting. Looks like that's a way of getting videos that are already on facebook to other places, which is the opposite of what we want, and what is currently working with youtube and possibly other sites that facebook has whitelisted.

Comment: Just bumping this, as I have the same issue. I seem to not be able to do what YouTube does. Anybody have an update if this feature has rolled out to the public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WizKid this is currently in a trial period for YouTube and hopefully will be rolled out to everyone at a future date.