# Embed html5 video player in facebook

Tags: html, facebook, video

I know this question has been asked many times.

I read everything on the topic.
It's exactly the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815838/embedding-video-player-html5-iframe-in-facebook-share-like-youtube)

I have a custom html5 video player that I'd like to use inside a facebook post, like youtube or vimeo does.

I added the correct meta tags but when I post the link of the player and click on play, I get a white screen with a "Download file" anchor.

It was suggested that this feature is on trial with youtube (and maybe vimeo or other partners)

Is it still the case or am I missing something ?
Do I need an app approval from facebook ?

Comment: How are you specifying your tags? According to the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#media), there is no guarantee that the video will play in-line, but there might be an issue in your meta tags.