# How to post a video in an ifram to facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, youtube

NOTE: I am opening a new question because all the other questions are not really related or with dead links.

Basically what i am trying to do is to post a video to Facebook and get it to play through my own html5 player. Kinda like Youtube.

Here is where I am at at the moment:

I have a page like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/embed/9yswzITbAbA) Youtube uses for embed videos, I can embed it in IFrames and all, but when I try to post it to facebook all what I am getting is ether an empty basic player (I am guessing facebook is trying to use my url as a video src) OR I get a link to my player that opens in a new tab.

I copied the FB meta tags Youtube uses (it's what got me the empty player):

> 

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
    <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://example.com/player#?vid=-KTVXcimOOFPgo2igeKf" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/player#?vid=-KTVXcimOOFPgo2igeKf" />

    <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />

    <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/share/asd.jpg">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />
    <meta name="attribution" content="Discovery/" />
```

Any help, tip, reference or a correction would be appreciated.

Comment: this is the most related question from 2 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815838/embedding-video-player-html5-iframe-in-facebook-share-like-youtube?rq=1   is it still a trial  ?

Comment: Yes it is. Only selected Facebook partners can post iframe content to timeline as of now.

Comment: Is there is a way to qualify to be one?

Comment: No, there is no official way to apply. Facebook picks the partners they want to run such tests with.